# How to use jquery with CompoundJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, compoundjs

I want to use jquery at server side with node.js mvc framework CompundJS. I want to use jquery  ($) in compundjs view. Can someone please tell me how to set up jquery in compundjs for that?

I have installed jQuery using "npm install". I want to use jQuery in compoundjs view to select and change some html tags at server side (depending on the data received from controller action). But I don't know how to configure compundjs for that.

Comment: There are server-side implementations of jQuery for Node, but what do you mean by you wanting to use jQuery in CompoundJS views? Could you explain what it is you want to use it for?

Comment: yes I have installed jQuery using "npm install". I want to use jQuery in compoundjs view to select and change some html tags at server side (depending on the data received from controller action). But I don't know how to configure compundjs for that.

Comment: I've taken a look at how CompoundJS renders views, and I don't think it's possible to do what you want. It doesn't provide any hooks to get the rendered HTML before it's sent to the client, unless you basically re-implement the `render()` function yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery on the server. Use the templating languages (that comes with compoundjs by default) instead, they allow you to change html dynamically depending on data that you make  available in the controller.

example (using ejs templates)

in app/controllers/somemodel_controller.js:

```
action('index', function(){
    this.title = "theTitle";
    this.dataToUseInView = "someData";
    this.mySpecialClass = "theClass";
    render();
});
```

in app/views/somemodel/index.ejs:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p class="<%= mySpecialClass%>"><%= dataToUseInView %></p>
```

will render:

```
<h1>theTitle</h1>
<p class="theClass">someData</p>
```

view the documentation for the templating language you use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CompoundJS, but usually on these frameworks you compile a template. A template has inputs - you should use them as a way to dynamically effect the html. For example, Jade template would allow you to 'inject' the page title:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
```

then you should have some kind of a render function that you can provide with 
`{pageTitle:"your title"}`

Comment: The issue is, as far as I understand, to let CompoundJS render a view and change the outcome of that action before the HTML is being sent back to the client, not just "how do I install jQuery on Node".

Comment: As I said, you should use templates to render these changes. He said he wants to use it on its server controller, using an action data that he can inject into a template.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood your answer, and I was probably too focused on getting to do what the OP is asking for instead of just realizing that, indeed, it can probably be solved from within the templates itself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY just like you use it in a HTML page. Compound do not have any role to play in this.

Just add link to your jquery file and in .ejs and use it as required.